# Graphics driver issue?

Tags: windows-10, display-driver

I have this issue (picture 1) when I'm trying to install some software on my laptop (ASUS VIVOBOOK L510MA/Windows 10 v10.0.19044 Build 19044 x64).

[image: Screenshot]

It is supposed to be like the picture 2 I attached to this question. But I can't expand the window.

I've tried to update the graphic driver through Driver Management, Windows Update, even I tried Driver Pack. But still, the issue is not fixed.

What should I do to fix it?

(CorelDraw installation window not properly run/show)

Comment: I'm doubting this is a graphics driver issue. It seems more like a software/installer issue or corrupted installer. Have you tried to redownload the install file? Can you get the install file from computer 2 onto computer 1 and try that?

Comment: I did redownload the install file, twice. Each with a different version, but still the same outcome! Also, I've tried install the software/installer onto a different computer, and it worked in that computer, but not in mentioned computer.

Comment: This is a paid product.  Have you asked their support department?

Comment: I have not, but I'll try, thanks

Comment: I have solved it accidentally. I rename the file with different name, and it worked! I don't know how is that working, but it's work anyway. Thanks.

Comment: How do I close this thread?

Comment: Add this as an answer to your own question

Comment: Also - mark your answer as accepted (click the ✔ sign).

Comment: Hahahaa.. yeah.. I accidentally answer my own question by just pressing a wrong button

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it accidentally. I rename the file with different name, and it worked! I don't know how is that working, but it's work anyway. Thanks.

So, this is how it solved:

1. Rename the setup.exe file with anything, e.g: setupp.exe, 123.exe, anything, literaly, really.
2. Run the installer
3. If there's error message shows up when it's installing (loading installation files), rename the file again to the original file name (Setup.exe)
4. Done!

Thanks everyone!